# Unconcatenate in SQL, Excel, SAS

Tags: sql, sas, concatenation

I have a data-file where the 'Clinical Event Result' column contains multiple clinical events labeled level 1-5.

I created code that extracts the first mentioned clinical event per level. For example, for someone with two level 4 events both 'Respiratory Assessment' and 'Patient Transport', only the 'Respiratory Assessment' will be extracted into another column.

```
USE EMTCQIData

SELECT FCT.[Financial Number], FCT.[Clinical Event Result], FCT.Level_5, 
FCT.Level_4, FCT.Level_3, CPT.CPT, MAX_FCT.MAX_FCT_CHARGE
FROM CPT_MASTER as CPT 
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT [Financial Number], [Clinical Event Result],

CASE

WHEN [Clinical Event Result] like '%1:1 Nursing care%' Then '1:1 Nursing 
Care'

WHEN [Clinical Event Result] like '%Admission or O.R. preparation%' Then 
'Admission/OR Preparation'

WHEN [Clinical Event Result] like '%Airway Management (BLS/ALS 
interventions)%' Then 'Airway Management'

WHEN [Clinical Event Result] like '%Critical care transport preparation%' 
Then 'Critical care transport preparation'

WHEN [Clinical Event Result] like '%Medical/code alert%' Then 'Medical/code 
alert'

WHEN [Clinical Event Result] like '%O2 therapy%' Then 'O2 therapy'

WHEN [Clinical Event Result] like '%Pain management with reassessment%' Then 
 'Pain management with reassessment'

WHEN [Clinical Event Result] like '%Respiratory monitoring%' Then 
'Respiratory monitoring'

END Level_5,

CASE

WHEN [Clinical Event Result] like '%Respiratory assessment%' Then 
'Respiratory assessment'

WHEN [Clinical Event Result] like '%Patient transport X-ray/CT%' Then 
'Patient transport X-ray/CT'

WHEN [Clinical Event Result] like '%Pulse oximetery%' Then 'Pulse oximetery'

WHEN [Clinical Event Result] like '%Cardiac monitoring%' Then 'Cardiac 
monitoring'

WHEN [Clinical Event Result] like '%Neurological monitoring%' Then 
'Neurological monitoring'

WHEN [Clinical Event Result] like '%Wound Care (less than 15 min)%' Then 
'Wound Care (less than 15 min)'

END Level_4,

CASE

WHEN [Clinical Event Result] like '%Blood-peripheral venous%' Then 'Blood-
```

peripheral venous'

```
WHEN [Clinical Event Result] like '%Urine-catheterized%' Then 'Urine-
```

catheterized'

```
WHEN [Clinical Event Result] like '%Oral hydration interventions%' Then 
'Oral hydration interventions'

WHEN [Clinical Event Result] like '%Oral meds%' Then 'Oral meds'

WHEN [Clinical Event Result] like '%Medication teaching%' Then 'Medication 
teaching'

WHEN [Clinical Event Result] like '%Vital signs monitoring%' Then 'Vital 
signs monitoring'

END Level_3

FROM ED_FCT_Q1_FY19

) 

as FCT ON FCT.[Financial Number]=CPT.FIN
INNER JOIN
 (
SELECT [Financial Number] as Fin, MAX(Charge_Code) as MAX_FCT_CHARGE

FROM ED_FCT_Q1_FY19

GROUP BY [Financial Number]

) as MAX_FCT on CPT.Fin = MAX_FCT.Fin
WHERE (FCT.[Clinical Event Result] like '%Level%' or FCT.[Clinical Event 
Result] like '%level%') AND CPT.CPT LIKE '9928%'
```

Table output:

```
[enter image description here][1]
```

How do I create a table that will show all of the level 4 events per patient, not just the first event?

Desired table output for example patient:

```
 **Patient ID|Clinical Event| Level 5 |Level 4| Level 4|Level 3**
```

Thank you!

Comment: if you can show your sample input and sample output, it will be easy for someone to help you

Comment: @kiran thanks! what is the best way to provide you with the sample output? Sorry, I'm new to the site and SQL!

Comment: An example of input and output is in the link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53344230/evaluate-string-fraction/53344784#53344784

Comment: @kiran thanks for the continued help, I updated my original post to show the full code that I'm using. I am unable to upload the output for this code but its essentially showing only one column per level and grabbing the first value associated per level. Id like the out to show as many levels as necessary. For example, if a patient has two level 4 values within their clinical event column, I would like that patients to have two separate rows with each one of their clinical events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a wide record with a flag variable for each result classification you want to have available in your analytics.

```
select
  …
  , WHEN [Clinical Event Result] like '%Respiratory assessment%' then 1 else 0 end
    as event_01_flag label='Respiratory assessment'
  , WHEN [Clinical Event Result] like '%Patient transport X-ray/CT%' then 1 else 0 end
    as event_02_flag label='Patient transport X-ray/CT'
  , …
```

With such an arrangement there are a variety of ways to report the event list on a per patient basis.  This answer can be expanded after the question is updated with a better example of the data you have, the roles of level and the hierarchies that might be represented therein, and the classification methods you are implementing prior to reporting the event list.

Comment: Thanks @Richard - please see the full code which was used in the following post

Comment: After the when/like statements concluded...
FROM ED_FCT_Q1_FY19

) 

as FCT ON FCT.[Financial Number]=CPT.FIN
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT [Financial Number] as Fin, MAX(Charge_Code) as MAX_FCT_CHARGE

FROM ED_FCT_Q1_FY19

GROUP BY [Financial Number]

) as MAX_FCT on CPT.Fin = MAX_FCT.Fin
WHERE (FCT.[Clinical Event Result] like '%Level%' or FCT.[Clinical Event Result] like '%level%') AND CPT.CPT LIKE '9928%'

Comment: When attempting to run the code you suggested  CASE
       WHEN [Clinical Event Result] like '%Respiratory assessment%' then 1 else 0 end as event_09_flag label='Respiratory assessment',
       WHEN [Clinical Event Result] like '%Patient transport X-ray/CT%' then 1 else 0 end as event_010_flag label='Patient transport X-ray/CT',...I recieved the following error Incorrect syntax near 'label'.

Comment: sorry about being nave, I'm new to SQL